# Can we use Opencv function estimateRigidTransform() in Java-Opencv

Tags: java, android, opencv

There's one useful function estimateRigidTransform() in C++ Opencv 
can we find in JAVA-OPENCV in android? 
My code is as following:
    Mat preFrame;
    Mat curFrame;
    Mat T=estimateRigidTransform(preFrame,curFrame,false);

Answer (score 0):

sure you can, it just might be hard to find (who would look in the video module for this ?) ;)

http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/video/Video.html#estimateRigidTransform(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20boolean)

Comment: I have done 'import org.opencv.video.Video;' but when i use estimateRidigTransform(Mat, Mat, boolean)  in my code. Eclipse warning that "The method estimateRigidTransform(Mat, Mat, boolean) is undefined for the type"

Comment: I am a freshman here.i don't know how to show my code professionaly<br/> <code> Mat preFrame, curFrame;<br/><code>Mat T=estimateRigidTransform(preFrame,curFrame,false);<br/>

Comment: There are some problem with my internet and part of my code is edited in my question and i have #import org.opencv.video.Video

Comment: it's `Mat T = Video.estimateRigidTransform(preFrame,curFrame,false);`